# MySQL: Error when using GROUP_CONCAT() in UPDATE

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting an UPDATE query using a temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE bookings_temporary AS (

    SELECT
        bookings_clients_options_data.bookings_client_option_data_id AS id

    FROM
        bookings_clients_options

    INNER JOIN
        bookings_attendees
        ON (bookings_clients_options.client_id = '3')

    INNER JOIN bookings_clients_options_data ON (bookings_clients_options_data.bookings_client_option_id = '4')
        AND (bookings_clients_options.bookings_client_option_id = bookings_clients_options_data.bookings_client_option_id)
        AND (bookings_clients_options_data.booking_attendee_id = bookings_attendees.booking_attendee_id)
        AND (bookings_clients_options_data.value = 'Y')

    ORDER BY id

);

UPDATE bookings_clients_options_data
SET status_booking='sent'
WHERE bookings_client_option_data_id IN (

    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM bookings_temporary WHERE id > 0

);

DROP TABLE bookings_temporary
```

While the SELECT query being used to populate the temporary table returns valid data, when I run the entire query, I get an error:

```
#1260 - Row 147 was cut by GROUP_CONCAT()
```

I tried appending the SELECT query with a LIMIT clause, which worked for the first 100, but then jammed at the next 100, which contains the problematic row 147.

I'm not sure how I would examine row 147 since it's contained within the temporary table, and its row number does not correspond with the originating table.

It's possible the whole thing is wrong, but since I can't go beyond the error, I can't speak any further on that.

Also, this doesn't appear to be an related to [group_concat_max_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) as the number of rows returned by the SELECT query is just 810, which is lower than the default 1024.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: You may need to increase this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len\

Comment: I considered that, but the number of rows returned by the SELECT query is just 810, which is lower than the default 1024.

Comment: Well not row that the string length in `group_concat`

Comment: Ah, you mean it's the entire string length, not the number of items? Okay, if so, I'll see if I can increase the value.

Comment: I had to set group_concat_max_len to 30000 and it worked. However, the query updated just the one row, which is the first row in the temporary table.

Comment: Yes that because you have used `in ('1,2,3')` here '1,2,3' i.e. ids are string and it will only use the first matching value

Comment: I just tried GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('\'', id, '\'')) and it hasn't updated anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73349/discussion-between-abhik-chakraborty-and-wayne-smallman).

Comment: Thats correct it will take `id as string` in group_concat, if you provide the table structures I can give you an update command with join.